# SQL using Rank and Row_Number with Order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, row-number

I am using SSMS 2018 and have a table similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE DxList (DocID INT, Dx VARCHAR(255), DxDate DATE, CreateDate DATETIME);

INSERT INTO DxList (DocID, Dx, DxDate, CreateDate)
VALUES (6018, 'OSDD', '10/01/2015', '10/09/2015 12:27');

INSERT INTO DxList (DocID, Dx, DxDate, CreateDate)
VALUES (6018, 'ADHD', '10/01/2015', '10/09/2015 18:14');
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM DxList

DocID   Dx      DxDate      CreateDate       
6018    OSDD    10/1/2015   10/9/2015 12:27   
6018    ADHD    10/1/2015   10/9/2015 18:14
```

I'd like to get the most recent `Dx` based on the `DxDate`. `Row_number` would work, however, if there is a tie like the one above (10/1/2015), I want the most recent to be based on the `CreateDate` instead.

In this case, I'd like my result to be:

```
DocID   Dx      DxDate      CreateDate        
6018    ADHD    10/1/2015   10/9/2015 18:14
```

I believe I can use `Rank()` with this query but I'm not sure how. This is my query so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  DocID,
  Dx,
  DxDate,
  CreateDate,
  rownum1,
  rank1
FROM (SELECT
  DocID,
  Dx,
  DxDate,
  CreateDate,
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DocID ORDER BY DxDate DESC) AS rank1,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocID ORDER BY DxDate DESC) AS rownum1
FROM DxList) b
WHERE rownum1 = 1
```

I believe I'm looking for something like:

> Order By (Case When rank1=rank1 then CreateDate else DxDate End) DESC

Of course this doesn't work because I need some sort of iteration and can't put it in the subquery. 
I also cannot use any derived tables to solve this issue. Is this possible?
Much appreciated!

Comment: i think your sample output is wrong because DocID   is different but according to your description  it would be same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `ROW_NUMBER` with a two-tiered `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT DocID, Dx, DxDate, CreateDate
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocID ORDER BY DxDate DESC, CreateDate DESC) rn
    FROM DxList
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The only major change in the above query versus what you had in mind is that two records with the same `DocID` and `DxDate` values would then be compared by the `CreateDate` to decide which one is really the "first."

### Demo

Note: In your demo the two records have *different* `DocID` values, but I think you intended for them to have the same value.  In the demo link above, I have changed the two records to have the same `DocID` value, and the logic is working.

Comment: I could scream by how complicated I made it. You are correct--this will work. In my real data, it is more complicated and DocID is actually different. However, I will change the sample data to make it more clear since I partitioned by the DocID. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use only ROW_NUMBER() and ORDER BY CreateDate   it will work.

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocID ORDER BY CreateDate DESC) AS rownum1

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample data just need below query

```
  SELECT top 1 *           
        FROM DxList
        order by DxDate desc,CreateDate desc
```

But According to your description follow @Tim provided query

here in this link both query you will find

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=44fdd4b2e849137cebe9df837ac41a39

```
DocID   Dx  DxDate  CreateDate
6018    ADHD    01/10/2015 00:00:00 09/10/2015 18:14:00
```